# Microsoft Graph API Beta Outlook Task Recurrence

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get Outlook tasks from the Graph API beta (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/task). It is basically working, but I get no recurrence for tasks in my Outlook.com account. This works fine for my Office 365 account.

Here is an example from Office 365:

```
        "recurrence": {
            "pattern": {
                "type": "absoluteYearly",
                "interval": 1,
                "month": 12,
                "dayOfMonth": 11,
                "firstDayOfWeek": "sunday",
                "index": "first"
            },
            "range": {
                "type": "noEnd",
                "startDate": "2018-12-11",
                "endDate": "0001-01-01",
                "recurrenceTimeZone": "UTC",
                "numberOfOccurrences": 0
            }
        }
```

And here is an example from Outlook.com, where I actually get two instances of the same recurring task, one with dueDateTime in the past and one inte future:

```
        "recurrence": null,
```

I have also tried this with the Outlook Task REST API (https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/tasks), which seems to be deprecated, with exactly the same results.

Comment: I have reproduce you question, however, it works with a Outlook.com Account.

Comment: Thanks to kikang I thought about the parameters I'm using. I am in fact filtering out not completed items: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks?$filter=Status%20ne%20'Completed'&$top=20` which seems not to include recurring tasks. When I remove the status filter I get some instances, but all are completed.

Comment: This is still different from the behaviour I get with Office 365.

Comment: I have tried this, it works. The result like this:

Comment: "categories": [],
            "importance": "normal",
            "status": "inProgress",
            "subject": "Test Recurring Task",
            "completedDateTime": null,
            "body": {
                "contentType": "html",
                "content": ""
            },
            "recurrence": {
                "pattern": {
                    "type": "weekly",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "month": 0,
                    }
     }